# Can I compile and dlopen a dynamic library in Compiler Explorer?

Tags: c++, lazy-loading, dynamic-linking, dlopen, compiler-explorer

Just for the purpose of learning, I've made a small example of a main program tentatively loeading a shared library via `dlopen` (and then a symbol from it via `dlsym`) and using a default one if the former is not avalable.

On my machine, to make the non-default library available to the main program, I need to compile the former via `g++ -fPIC -shared MyLib.cpp -o libMyLib.so`, whereas both `main.cpp`  and `DefaultLib.cpp` are compiled simply by `g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o` and `g++ -c DefaultLib.cpp -o DefaultLib.o`. How can I provide the options `-fPIC -shared` to the compilation of `MyLib.cpp` in Compiler Explorer?

The current attempt is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/jhPeo316q), where, I believe, `MyLib.cpp` is compiled just like the other two `cpp` files, i.e. without providing options `-fPIC` and `-shared`, and maybe most importantly without generating a file with the name `libMyLib.so`, thus resulting `dlopen` failing to load; indeed, the `foo` from the other, default library `DefaultLib` is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I compile and dlopen a dynamic library in Compiler Explorer?

Yes, it's certainly possible.

In `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(MyLib SHARED MyLib.cpp)
```

...and remove `MyLib.cpp` from `add_executable`.

Then in `main.cpp`:

```
void * lib = dlopen("build/libMyLib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

Because the library is placed in the `build` subdirectory.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cThKEb58z)

Comment: It is better to use `MODULE` instead of `SHARED` when build a library intended for dlopen. E.g. such library could contain undefined symbols (which are defined by the program which calls `dlopen`). But SHARED library cannot contain undefined symbols: the linker will emit an error in such case.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Oh.... Are the `.so` files instrumented differently somehow? When does the linker error occur? When creating the actual `.so` file? I've never had that problem so I don't know. Also, I'm a bit of a CMake rookie.

Comment: "When does the linker error occur?" - This is well-known "undefined reference" error which is emitted when the linker links objects files and static libraries into the shared one (`.so`). For avoid such error when create a library for `dlopen` usage, its linker's command line should have different options. This is why CMake introduces MODULE library type. Also, CMake doesn't create soversion (like `.so.1.2`) for a MODULE library (On Windows a MODULE library has more specifics. E.g. its creation doesn't involve creation of the import file (`.lib`) which usually accompanies a `.dll`.)

Comment: "I've never had that problem so I don't know." - Actually, I was too unaware about such difference until I have tried to use "plugin" approach for my project:)

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ok, I've never gotten the "undefined reference" error when making my shared libraries so I wonder what could be causing it (if I've done everything else right of course). I need to check what differs in the commands issued by CMake when using `SHARED`  compared to `MODULE` to find out what the difference in the final library is I guess. I've created quite a few of `.so`s and `.dll`s (without `.lib`s) that I load at will at runtime and so far it has "just worked". I have however never used CMake to create them so perhaps I "got it right" by pure luck :-)